# Image upload script to be more dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working script that shows a preview of a image a user is wanting to upload which works fine for a single image upload. I now what to use this script on a multiple image upload and would like to have the readURL function in the script work dynamically so I don't have to repeat the lines

```
 $("#patient_pic1").live("change",function(){
        readURL(this, "#preview_image1")
     });
```

for every upload container

here is my html

```
<div class="upload-file-container"> <img id="preview_image1" class="preimg" src="#" alt="" />
  <input type="file"  id="patient_pic1" name="pic[]" class="photo" />
</div>
<div class="upload-file-container"> <img id="preview_image2" class="preimg" src="#" alt="" />
  <input type="file"  id="patient_pic2" name="pic[]" class="photo" />
</div>
```

and the Jquery

```
function readURL(input, target) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var image_target = $(target);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image_target.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
         }
     }

          $("#patient_pic1").live("change",function(){
    readURL(this, "#preview_image1")
 });
       $("#patient_pic2").live("change",function(){
readURL(this, "#preview_image2")
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6j1kr549/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
 $('input[type="file"]').on("change",function(){
     var target = '#'+$(this).parent().find('img').attr('id');
    readURL(this, target);
 });
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6j1kr549/2/)**

Comment: Is good, but it will get any control of type "File", with a IF statement can be better.

Comment: Yeah but that's what the user wants to include all "File" types.

Comment: Maby define the scope by .upload-file-container input[type="file"] or .upload-file-container .photo. because he wants all the file inputs from the uploading section ? and not from the whole page i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the each() funtion to loop all classes with a same name and get the input controls for each element inside the class:
PD: Counter is For clarification, but is funtional:

```
var counter = 1;
$('.upload-file-container').each(function() {
    $(this, "#patient_pic" + counter.toString()).live("change",function(){
        readURL(this, "#preview_image" + counter.toString())
     });
     counter = counter + 1;
});
```